# Can I configure SSMA to use DB2 server_encrypt authentication?

Tags: sql-server, database, db2

I am trying to use Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for DB2 (version 7.5.0) to migrate a DB2 11.1 database to MS SQL 2014. The DB2 connection used to work, but fails after the administrator changed the DB2 authentication method from the default of “server” to “server_encrypt” to meet an audit requirement. Now when I connect to the the DB2 server, I am getting the following error:
Connection to DB2 failed.
The authentication method used is not supported by the remote system. Contact your system administrator.

Is it possible to configure SSMA to use the DB2 server_encrypt authentication method?  If so, how?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If the Windows server that runs MS-SQL-Server is a different hostname from the machine running Db2-server, then ensure that the *DB2-client* on the MS-SQL-Server hostname is the latest available fixpack of Db2 V11.1 *and* uncatalog and recatalog the Db2 database on the Windows-hostname with the correct authentication detail per Db2 documentation.

Comment: HI mao.  Thanks for your response. I do not have any DB2 client software installed on the workstation running SSMA other than the OleDB for DB2 client from Microsoft. The connectivity to the server is OK, it is just the authentication method that is causing SSMA a problem.

Comment: According to other sources, the Microsoft OLEDB Provider for DB2 supports SERVER_ENCRYPT authentication since the SQL-Server-2008.  (Older versions did not support SERVER_ENCRYPT). I don't know the history at your site of when this link was created and upgraded over the years. Have you tried dropping the link to DB2 in SSMA (using Microsoft's instructions) and then re-creating it?

Comment: Thank you mao. I will try recreating the DB2 connection.

Comment: I could not get the default connection dialog box to connect to my DB2 server using the server_encrypt authentication method.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to connect using the Connection String mode and the following connection string:
Provider=DB2OLEDB;User ID=useName;Password=password;Initial Catalog=dbName;Network Transport Library=TCPIP;Host CCSID=37;PC Code Page=1252;Network Address=serverName;Network Port=portNbr;Default Schema=schemaName;Units of Work=RUW;DBMS Platform=DB2/MVS;Use Early Metadata=False;Defer Prepare=False;DateTime As Char=False;Rowset Cache Size=0;Binary CodePage=0;Datetime As Date=False;AutoCommit=True;Authentication=Server_Encrypt_UsrPwd;Decimal As Numeric=False;Allow Null Chars=False;LoadBalancing=False;Persist Security Info=False;Cache Authentication=False;Connection Pooling=False;Literal Replacement=False;